# How to copy and add prefix to file names in one step from another directory?

Tags: files, rename, cp, file-copy

I want to copy and rename multiple files from one directory to another.
Particularly, I want something like this:

```
/tmp/tmp.XXX/aaa.original.txt
/tmp/tmp.XXX/bb5.original.txt
/tmp/tmp.XXX/x2x.original.txt
```

copied into

```
/root/hello/dump-aaa.txt
/root/hello/dump-bb5.txt
/root/hello/dump-x2x.txt
```

I've tried some things like these which don't work:

- `cp /tmp/tmp.XXX/*.original.txt /root/hello/*.txt`
- `find /tmp/tmp.XXX/ -name '*.original.txt' | xargs -i cp /root/hello/dump-{}.txt`
- `for f in /tmp/tmp.XXX/*.original.txt; do cp -- "$f" "/root/hello/dump-$f.txt"; done`

Usually the above codes result in **error**:

`cp: cannot create regular file '/root/hello/dump-/tmp/tmp.XXX/aaa.original.txt.txt': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`bash`** solution:

```
for f in /tmp/tmp.XXX/*.original.txt; do 
    bn="${f##*/}"   # extracting file basename
    cp "$f" "/root/hello/dump-${bn%%.*}.txt"
done
```